# Using onChange={} and event handlers in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        key: myUUID,
        title: "",
        author: "",
        questions: [],
        answers: []
      }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

Ok so I am trying to make it so when the user types into this input `<input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange}/>` the "value" of it updates to what the user is inputing. Currently when I type in the input box, the characters I type do not show up and the state (title) for this input does not seem to update. I am new to React and JS so any tips/pointers/explanation of what's happening will be much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's the render method (there's more in it than just this so I consolidated)

```
 render () {
    //yada yada
    <div>
          <form>
            <div className="Intro">
              Give your Quiz a title: <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
              Who's the Author? <input type="text" /><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <div className="questions">
              Now let's add some questions... <br/>
              {this.addQuestion}
            </div>
          </form>
          <button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
        </div>

     //yada yada
 }
export default App;
```

Comment: Could you include the render method from your `App` component as well?

Comment: handleChange is checking `target.name`, but it doesn't look like your input element has a name.

Comment: @AlexYoung I added the Render function there for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the `name` prop to your `input` components. These props should be set to their respective keys in the state.

Example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            key: myUUID,
            title: "",
            author: "",
            questions: [],
            answers: []
        };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} name='title' />
                <input type="text" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange} name='author' />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Edited for clarity**

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but they did not work, till having the same problem

Comment: Updated with follow up after seeing render function.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So I added `value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange}` to my "Who's the author?" input right after the title input and now the author input updates the title input. Do you perhaps know why this is so?

Comment: Yes, because in your `handleChange` function, you are are now updating only `title`. If you want to dynamically update the input, I can update my answer to show you how to accomplish that.

Comment: Oh, yes please that would be helpful